# Silverlight ListBox binding with canvas and images

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, listbox, customization

I try make custom listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ImageList" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageControls}" Width="256" Height="256" Margin="256,0,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Width" Value="128" />
                <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Height" Value="128" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Source}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now i have problem with binding... `ImageList.ItemsSource` is always null.

I have property

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageControl> ImageControls;
```

It Contains collection of the

```
public class ImageControl
{
    public WriteableBitmap Source { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Left { get; set; }
}
```

I need to see somethink like that:
[image]

In result, after adding list elements from code i want to receive items like (images with sources):

```
        <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="128" Height="128">
            <Image x:Name="Image1"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="128" Canvas.Top="0" Width="128" Height="128">
            <Image x:Name="Image2"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="128" Width="128" Height="128">
            <Image x:Name="Image3"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Canvas.Left="128" Canvas.Top="128" Width="128" Height="128">
            <Image x:Name="Image4" />
        </ListBoxItem>
```

In code i adds images like this:

```
ImageControls.Add(new ImageControl { Source = _bmp, Left = 0, Top = 0});
```

What i do wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: "ImageList.ItemsSource is always null" -- what is the DataContext of the ListBox? It must be the class that has the ImageControls property. When do you initialize ImageControls? Is it before or after InitializeComponent? If after are you firing a Propertychanged event?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is the way you have declared the **Source property** in your **ImageControl class**. It uses a **WriteableBitmap** (I haven't use it). However, in your XAML code, the **Source property** for the **Image control** expect that you specify a kind of string o Uri type.
Try changing the Source property in your ImageControl class as string.

```
public class ImageControl
{
   public string Source { get; set; }
   public int Top { get; set; }
   public int Left { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: But i need the Source as WritableBitmap, not a string. And when i hard coded list items (which i wrote in the end) i can change its image sources with Writable bitmap, they changes and all works correctly(but items hard coded in this variant).

Answer (score 0):

Works! I add to my control constructor this:

```
ImageControls = new ObservableCollection<ImageControl>();
(It was before)InitializeComponent();
ImageList.ItemsSource = ImageControls;
```

I.e. I add binding source on init.
And later I just work with my `ImageControls` collection, like this:

```
ImageControls.Add(new ImageControl { Left = 128, Source = _bmp, Top = 0 });
```

And listbox items adds!